# Tutorials: Writing Simple Server Client Bug?

Tags: ros, tutorial, beginner-tutorials, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

so I'm doing the tutorials and I got a problem in this one.

Where do you get this file? #include "beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h"?

I know that you have to go back look at  creating the AddTwoInts.srv Tutorial.

But my problem is how do you get the .h file?

This file is needed for both service and client.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203963/tutorials:-writing-simple-server-client-bug?/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to find it.
It is going to be created during compiling. To do that add the following line in your cmakelists

```
add_executable(add_two_ints_server src/add_two_ints_server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_server beginner_tutorials_gencpp)    // <= you need this line
```

from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29).

Of course it is mandatory to create at first your srv file in the project folder as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_srv).

In the right order:

1. create the srv file and add it into your cmakelists;
2. add the above line as at the beginning suggested (to tell the compiler to generate the needed .h file at first);
3. compile with `catkin_make`;

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2015-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on 2015-02-28**:
Hum I had those lines included in my CMakeLists.txt, I followed the tutorial.

I get the this error when I do the catkin_make:

```
/home/paulo/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp:2:43: fatal error: beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h: No such file or directory
 #include "be
```

**Comment by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on 2015-02-28**:
#include "beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h"
^
/home/paulo/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp:2:43: fatal error: beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h: No such file or directory
#include "beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h"